# Too many use cases in use case diagram - Can't fit boundary. Any way of simplifying?

Tags: analysis, uml, use-case

I am new to UML modelling and I was creating this use case and generalised the use cases into 4 main categories - Add info, View info, edit info and delete info. Each generalisation contains 6 use cases so in total it gives about 28 use cases and its difficult to fit them all in one system boundary whilst making it easy to understand. Can someone please advise please advise how I can overcome this?

Below is what i have so far. I have yet to add EditInformation and DeleteInformation but i've run out of space.

Many thanks

[image: use case diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Use-cases` are the description of the highest level behavior of the system. You shouldn't dwell into the lower level details. Normally, a system would have no more than several use-cases. According to your description, your actual `use-cases` are what you classified as categories: `Add info`, `View info`, `Edit info` and `Delete info`. Finer details such as `ViewCar` or `AddBooking` belong to the corresponding `sequence/activity diagrams`.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your answer. I understand what you said regarding but the teacher doesnt have access to adding all information. he only has access to add 3 out of 6 use cases. Also, From what i have researched under advanced use case modelling, i found the concept of use case generalisation. an example is found here. http://businessanalystmastery.com/use-case-docu-mistake-3-improper-use-case-associations

Comment: Use-case generalization is a new concept to me so I can't comment on it. Regarding the restrictions that you describe - I believe they don't belong to the use-case diagram but to a lower-level design documents.

Comment: @icepack, could you back up your answer with references to some sources?

Answer (score 1):

You can set for yourself a limit of how many artefacts you would put on a diagram at maximum. For example, you might say that all diagramms shall fit on a certain standard page format when printed. Typically, it is not the purpose of abstracting the use cases to a level where they all fit on one diagram but reveal no added value any more. You'd end up in a use case chart for a space rocket merely saying nothing but "launch spacecraft". Instead, try to identify such use cases on a highly abstract level and then you break them down into more detailed ones on subordinate diagrams. In most modeling tools you can create links between several diagrams. If you'd like to read more, I'd recommend Alistair Cockburn's standard book on use cases, ISBN 978-0201702255